# My code is not inserting data into database

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I had an old mysql code where it successfully inserted values into the database. But as that people are now stating that mysqli is better to use (can't use PDO because of my version of php is below 5.3), I have tried to change my code so that it uses mysqli instead of mysql.

The problem is that it now does not insert values into the database since making this change. I am a mysqli novice so I would really appreciate it if somebody can help me change the code below so that mysqli can be used to insert data into the database. What am I doing wrong? There are no errors in the error report.

Below is my current attempt on this:

```
    $username="xxx";
    $password="xxx";
    $database="mobile_app";

      $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", $username, $password, $database);

      /* check connection */
      if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
        die();
      }

    $sql = "SELECT TeacherId FROM Teacher WHERE (TeacherUsername = ?)";

    $stmt=$mysqli->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bind_param("s",$_SESSION['teacherusername']);
    $stmt->execute();
    $record = $stmt->fetch();
    $teacherid = $record['TeacherId'];




    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')

    {

    $time = str_replace(array(' Hrs ', ' Mins ', ' Secs'), array(':', ':', ''), $_SESSION['durationChosen']);

    $insertsql = "INSERT INTO Session (SessionId, SessionTime, SessionDate, SessionWeight, SessionDuration, TotalMarks, ModuleId, TeacherId, Room) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
    $insert = $mysqli->prepare($insertsql);


for ($i = 1, $n = $_SESSION['sessionNum']; $i <= $n; ++$i) {
    $sessid = $_SESSION['id'] . ($n == 1 ? '' : $i);
    $sessdate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($_SESSION['dateChosen']));

    $insert->bind_param("sssssssss", $sessid, $_SESSION['timeChosen'], $sessdate,
                     $_SESSION['textWeight'], $time, $_SESSION['textMarks'],
                     $_SESSION['module'], $teacherid, $_SESSION['rooms']);

    $insert->execute();
}


    }
```

Comment: Did you call session_start()?

Comment: @Musa Yes I have called session_start() and all the isset of the $_SESSIONS at the top of the code

Comment: Do you get any error when executing the insert? What do you see when you print the variable $insertsql as a string? Are all input values 'quoted' as necessary? Do the data types of the inputs match your table schema?

Comment: @GirishRao I have done a print $insertsql and now I am getting 2 errors now which are these: 
`Warning: mysqli::prepare() [mysqli.prepare]: All data must be fetched before a new statement prepare takes place in ... on line 146` and

`Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object in ... on line 155`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're missing the ending quote on this line:

```
$insertsql = "INSERT INTO Session (
    SessionId, SessionTime, SessionDate, SessionWeight,
    SessionDuration, TotalMarks, ModuleId, TeacherId, Room) 
VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);
```

Make it

```
$insertsql = "INSERT INTO Session (
    SessionId, SessionTime, SessionDate, SessionWeight,
    SessionDuration, TotalMarks, ModuleId, TeacherId, Room) 
VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
```

It also looks like you need to put your for loop before you bind the params, since you're using the results of said for loop in the bind.

Comment: strange I did not get a syntax error on this but it is still not inserting the data into the database. There is no misspelling, the field names in the query are correct but still not inserting data in database

Comment: @user1421767 Ok, looks like your order of operations is off, you are trying to bind $sessid and $sessdate before they are defined. Move the for loop to before the bind_param call.

Comment: @Greg OK, I moved the whole for loop above the bind param as you stated but still not inserting data into the database

Comment: @Greg Btw I updated code in question so you can see what current code now looks like

Comment: Looks like you moved the bind_param after the execute. You'll want to put bind_param between the for loop and the execute statement;

Comment: My execute command is in the for loop so are you saying put the bind param in the for loop but put it before the execute?

Comment: @Greg I have tried what you have stated but still no luck. In error report it is still giving me the 2 errors mentioned in question. Code is updated in question